# Unity standalone build auto detect resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unity app for Mac and Windows.
When I build it as standalone and open the app/exe file it gives a screen to select the resolution and some other options.
Is it possible to make it auto detect the current computer's resolution(by writing a script for that) and auto open the window when we double click the exe or app file and open with that resolution correctly without showing that screen to select resolution.

If it's possible please let me know how I can do that.

Thanks

Comment: There are many questions in [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) and the [Unity Forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/forum.php) that discuss this.  I know because I once had to do this and found everything I needed there.  Also... don't forget to the consult the [documentation for Screen](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Screen.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I forgot to search there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Screen.SetResolution (Screen.currentResolution.width, Screen.currentResolution.height, true);
```

This sets it to fullscreen and detects your current desktop resolution.

To go back to windowed mode use

```
Screen.SetResolution (1024, 768, false); //enter res
```

The problem most people have is resizing the GUI, which is beyond my range of knowledge in Unity3D. Hope that helps you a little.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helped me. (sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote up).  For anyone looking at the question this is what I did. First I disabled the resolution dialog box from Unity - Edit - Project settings - Player- Resolution. Then added above line to Awake() function in my script.

Comment: I think we can resize GUI elements by giving dynamic values in RECT. 
For example, if I have a full screen image that is 1024 x 768, then I will give values in RECT as `new Rect(0,0,1024*(Screen.width/1024),768*(Screen.height/768))`
It is just a hypothesis, I am new to 3D world, but I used to use this technique frequently in 2D environment.

You check this and hope for the best :)

Thank you

Comment: What I want is to get current player resolution