# Automatic quality settings

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

a lot of apps that I see nowadays(Android) instead of having an options screen to select the graphical level, it just automatically does it, I know this is kind of a vast question, but how can I do that for my own app? any links/resources that I can look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from [GameQualitySettings.js](https://www.assembla.com/code/pgrad2012/subversion/nodes/Unity/Bootcamp/Assets/Scripts/huds/GameQualitySettings.js?rev=113) of the [Bootcamp demo](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/1376) that addresses dynamic quality settings:

```
function AutoChooseQualityLevel ()
{
    var shaderLevel = SystemInfo.graphicsShaderLevel;
    var fillrate = SystemInfo.graphicsPixelFillrate;
    var vram = SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize;
    var cpus = SystemInfo.processorCount;
    if (fillrate < 0)
    {
        if (shaderLevel < 10)
            fillrate = 1000;
        else if (shaderLevel < 20)
            fillrate = 1300;
        else if (shaderLevel < 30)
            fillrate = 2000;
        else
            fillrate = 3000;
        if (cpus >= 6)
            fillrate *= 3;
        else if (cpus >= 3)
            fillrate *= 2;
        if (vram >= 512)
            fillrate *= 2;
        else if (vram <= 128)
            fillrate /= 2;
    }

    var resx = Screen.width;
    var resy = Screen.height;
    var fillneed : float = (resx*resy + 400*300) * (30.0 / 1000000.0);
    var levelmult : float[] = [5.0, 30.0, 80.0, 130.0, 200.0, 320.0];

    var level = 0;
    while (level < QualityLevel.Fantastic && fillrate > fillneed * levelmult[level+1])
        ++level;

    //print (String.Format("{0}x{1} need {2} has {3} = {4} level", resx, resy, fillneed, fillrate, level));

    overallQuality = level;
    UpdateAllSettings ();
}
```

This snippet obviously lacks all the functionality of the original script but posting the full script seemed overkill.   You can dynamically control quality with the [QualitySettings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel.html) class.

And if you need to set the resolution, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20415762/unity-standalone-build-auto-detect-resolution) was asked.

Comment: That scripts seems kinda complicated :/, but it seems to work from my understanding, thanks for the referenc, I'll accept it and later on I might work with it

Answer (score 1):

*I haven't verified that this fillrate computation method is still very effective!*

I converted the Bootcamp AutoChooseQualityLevel to C# for Unity 5+ (graphicsPixelFillrate no longer exists so we must use the fillrate computation). I also tried to decode what some of the esoteric parts do.

Assumes you have an eQualityLevel enum that matches your QualitySettings.names values.

```
eQualityLevel AutoChooseQualityLevel()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(QualitySettings.names.Length == Enum.GetNames(typeof(eQualityLevel)).Length, "Please update eQualityLevel to the new quality levels.");

    var shaderLevel = SystemInfo.graphicsShaderLevel;
    var vram = SystemInfo.graphicsMemorySize;
    var cpus = SystemInfo.processorCount;
    var fillrate = 0;
    if (shaderLevel < 10)
        fillrate = 1000;
    else if (shaderLevel < 20)
        fillrate = 1300;
    else if (shaderLevel < 30)
        fillrate = 2000;
    else
        fillrate = 3000;
    if (cpus >= 6)
        fillrate *= 3;
    else if (cpus >= 3)
        fillrate *= 2;
    if (vram >= 512)
        fillrate *= 2;
    else if (vram <= 128)
        fillrate /= 2;

    var resx = Screen.width;
    var resy = Screen.height;
    var target_fps = 30.0f;
    var fillneed = (resx*resy + 400f*300f) * (target_fps / 1000000.0f);
    // Change the values in levelmult to match the relative fill rate
    // requirements for each quality level.
    var levelmult = new float[] { 5.0f, 30.0f, 80.0f, 130.0f, 200.0f, 320.0f };

    const int max_quality = (int)eQualityLevel.Fantastic;
    var level = 0;
    while (level < max_quality && fillrate > fillneed * levelmult[level+1])
        ++level;

    var quality = (eQualityLevel)level;
    Debug.Log(string.Format("{0}x{1} need {2} has {3} = {4} level", resx, resy, fillneed, fillrate, quality.ToString()));

    return quality;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but this might be what you want [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html)